# cannot correctly use "psql" command-line via subprocess.call in my script

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run a command like this in python:

```
subprocess.call(['psql', '--username=openerp', '--dbname=sf_template', '--no-password', '--command="select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname = \'sf_template\' and procpid <> pg_backend_pid()"'], env={'PGPASSWORD': 'mypassword'})
```

And I get the following verbose output:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<myCurrentOSuser>"
```

But if I run this command by shell:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword
psql --username=openerp --dbname=sf_template --no-password --command="select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'sf_template' and procpid <> pg_backend_pid()"
```

It works properly.

**Why**? What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't need the quotes

Comment: To find out how the argument list should look like, call `shlex.split(r'''psql --username=openerp --dbname=sf_template --no-password --command="select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'sf_template' and procpid <> pg_backend_pid()"''')`

Comment: use `env=dict(os.environ, PGPASSWORD='mypassword')` to avoid clearing the environment.

Answer (score 2):

(Thanks for the first three commenters - I solved the problem with your help).

I sent the whole arguments to `subprocess.call` as one single string (did not fully understand the array syntax).

```
subprocess.call(['psql --username=openerp --dbname=sf_template --no-password --command="select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname = \'sf_template\' and procpid <> pg_backend_pid()"'], env={'PGPASSWORD': 'mypassword'})
```